# How to get filled points when you use geom_point() in a ggplot graphic

Tags: r

Hi dear I am working with two continuous variables. When I made a ggplot graphic I used this code:

```
p4 <- ggplot(DataBase, aes(x=x, y=y))+xlab("Porcentaje de Tamaño Acumulado")+ylab("Porcentaje de Monto Acumulado")
p4 + geom_line(colour="darkblue",size = 1.5)+geom_point(colour = "red", size = 4,,shape=5)
```

I got this picture:

[image]

Where the points are empty. It is possible to fill them. I tried with `fill` but I got the same result. Thanks.

Comment: Change shape... to 18.

Comment: see `?pch` for all of em.